# How get the object name that the running function belongs to?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to write a db abstraction in node js and here is the situation :

Imagine I have a tables array of objects which has an object for each table in the database :

```
tables = [{ tableName: product, select: mySelect  }, { tableName: order, select: mySelect  }]
```

and as you can see each table has a select. Now the problem is that in mySelect function I would like to generate a sql script based on caller's table name as follows :

```
function mySelect(){
  var tableName = //Find the callers name (for instance product);
  var select = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName
}
```

how can I get the name of the object which is calling the select function in JavaScript?

Comment: You could use `var tableName = arguments.callee.name` but it won't work in strict mode.

Comment: Maybe just pass in the argument you want? How are you calling mySelect? Either have separate functions for selecting different things, or pass in an argument.

Comment: The thing is I don't want to pass an argument. I want to get something like :
db.product.select()
So in the select function I need to somehow understand that it was called from product object. This way I can generate a SQL statement against product table .
BTW arguments.callee.name returns the name of the function that is being called , I need the name of the object from which select was called.

Answer (score 3):

```
 function myfunc() {  alert(arguments.callee.name); } 
 b = myfunc; 
 b();
```

***This will write  "myfunc" (FF, Chrome,and I think Safari)***

If you want to get name from outside you may parse it out of:

```
 b.toString();
```

**But I think name property of function object might be what you need:**

```
alert(b.name);
```

Im have read that this is no available in **IE and Opera** so you are left with parsing it out manually in those browsers.

**Antoher alternative**

```
 function antoherFunction(args) {
    var ret = args.toString();
    ret = ret.substr('function '.length);
    ret = ret.substr(0, ret.indexOf('('));
    return ret;
 }
```

But..  to use **Function.caller** is non-standard and **arguments.callee** is forbidden in **strict mode**.

Answer (score 0):

You can always send the table name as a parameter to the function.

for e.g

```
for(var i = 0, len = tables.length; i < len; i++)
{
   tables[i].select(tables[i].tableName);
}
```

or if your objects are like ORM(object relational model) where each table has their own class then you can just use this.constructor or this.tableName as your objects already contain tables name.

for e.g

```
function mySelect(){
    var tableName = this.constructor;
    // or tableName = this.tableName;

    var select = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you every one actually this article helped me out.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

using bind function when I'm creating my db.tables I bind the select function to the current table object :

```
for(var i=0; i< tables.length; i++){
    db.tables[tables[i].tablename] = {};
    db.tables[tables[i].tablename].select = select.bind(tables[i]);
}
```

this way I can make sure that "this" keyword always refers to "product" object when I call for instance the select function of product object.